# (C++) a problem regarding on quick-pow func (a^^b)mod c

Tags: c++, biginteger

I use a quick_pow func to calculate **a^^b** (a=2, b is more than 400), and at the same time, I also need **mod** to get lower positions num as the output of leetcode exercise.
With hours' checking, I finally located the problem coming from my qpow() func. But after I change it to an easier way in qpow2(), it does give correct answer. So I tried a simple code to see the difference. As you can see in my screenshot, **qpow() gets wrong in "-83648" and then keeps "0" after that**. Could you please let me know what is going on here? Thanks a lot.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<cstring>
#include<algorithm>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int qpow(int n) {
    int x = 1, a = 2;
    while (n > 0) {
        if (n % 2) {
            x *= a;
            x %= 100000;
        };
        a *= a;
        a %= 100000;
        n /= 2;
    };
    return x;
};

int qpow2(int n) {
    int x = 1, a = 2;
    while (n--)
    {
        x *= a;
        x %= 100000;
    };
    return x;
};

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 10; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << qpow(i) << " | ";
        cout << qpow2(i) << " | ";
        cout << INT_MAX << endl;
    };
    return 0;
};
```

[TRYING 2^^50](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlfdZ.png)

Comment: `int` can hold `2^^31 - 1` at most, it would be hard to use it for `2^^50`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen thank you. so would it be better if i avoid using quickpow while computing with "mod c"? because it seems like qpow2() with a regular way can give me the right answer...

Comment: `a *= a;` overflows when `a` is 65536. The second never grows above 99999*2.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks for your answer! It's clear now.